# React.jsx: type is invalid - React Datatable

Tags: javascript, reactjs

For some reason I am receiving this error only when my DataTable component is on the page, when commended out, the page renders fine. I have another DataTable component on a different page which loads fine so I'm pretty confused.

Below is the row that the DataTable Component is on:

```
<Row>
                <Col>
                    <Card>      
                        <CardHeader className='border-bottom'>
                            <CardTitle tag='h4'>DataTable</CardTitle>
                        </CardHeader>
                        <Row className='justify-content-end mx-0'>
                            <Col className='d-flex align-items-center justify-content-end mt-1' md='6' sm='12'>
                            <Label className='mr-1' for='search-input-1'>
                                <Search size={20} />
                            </Label>
                            <Input
                                className='dataTable-filter mb-50'
                                type='text'
                                bsSize='sm'
                                id='search-input-1'
                                value={searchValue}
                                onChange={handleFilter}
                            />
                            </Col>
                        </Row>
                        {/* <DataTable
                            noHeader
                            pagination
                            selectableRowsNoSelectAll
                            columns={columns}
                            className='react-dataTable'
                            paginationPerPage={10}
                            sortIcon={<ChevronDown size={10} />}
                            paginationDefaultPage={currentPage + 1}
                            data={searchValue.length ? filteredData : data}
                        /> */}
                    </Card>   
                </Col>
            </Row>
```

When it is uncommented out, i get a few errors like such:

**React.jsx: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.**

**Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.**

As it references my import, here is the route for said component:

```
{
    path: '/contractor-upload',
    component: lazy(() => import('../../views/UploadContractors'))
  },
```

Comment: Can you share the import statement of the DataTable? Pls check and compare where it works and where it does not.

Comment: I'm an idiot, I had it imported like { DataTable } instead of DataTable. Thank you lol